# Community wiki and potential reputation

Tags: support

I am getting tired of people who find a question that is:

- not subjective
- not off-topic
- not intended to have the community edit it

but:

- has the potential to gain many upvotes

and say that it should be converted to community wiki or they will threaten to close it. It seems like they are just jealous of not being able to come up with a good question that can gain many upvotes.

Community wiki is not to balance out reputation for jealous people. Community wiki is for questions that suit community input through editing from low-reputation users as well as those past the typical editing threshold.

Can we add this to the FAQ so that people stop nagging for community wiki?

Comment: Link or it didn't happen. (^_^)

Comment: It *is* a part of the FAQ: [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: The FAQ should state, however, that community wiki shouldn't be used as an excuse by people to stop good questions from getting upvotes.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. Can you provide a sample?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3707791 -- the first commenter thinks that *subjective* equals *wiki time*.

Comment: Another, independent example: [would you prefer coding php using framework or on it's own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732831/would-you-prefer-coding-php-using-framework-or-on-its-own).

Comment: @Delan your question *is* subjective and too localized to your situation: it'd probably be better served on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). The appropriate alternative to *community wiki* would be to close it, not leave it open.

Comment: @Mark I wouldn't call closing an alternative to CW for that. I'd call it the proper course of action. Delan is right that CW should be used for questions that require community interaction, not as a measure to block reputation change or allow an otherwise disallowed question.

Comment: @Grace I'm in agreement: I was pointing out that Delan's alternative to the inappropriateness of CW—to leave his question alone—was incorrect: the appropriate action is to close.

Answer (score 4):

In a way I'd say you're right.  Questions as subjective as the example you gave should just be closed.  No need to bother making them Community Wiki.  Your question [Where to go now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707791/where-to-go-now) might be asked on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, but I haven't really got a fix on what kinds of questions will get closed on there.  You'll just have to try it and see.

Answer (score 2):

Those are the very models of a modern subjective question: [what language should I learn next](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3707791) and "[would you prefer (sic!) coding php using framework or on its own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732831/would-you-prefer-coding-php-using-framework-or-on-its-own)".

[From the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!

What sort of objective answer do you envision for a question titled "where to go next?" - "second to the right, and straight on till morning"? Or for a question "do you prefer a framework?"

It's perhaps inevitable that your opinion differs from other users', but IMNSHO by complaining about that, you are being *slightly* too sensitive about your precious rep points.

Comment: Now everyone upvote this or I'll go to meta.meta.SO to complain that the meta users won't recognize the upvote potential of my answer.

Comment: Yes, but where is the correlation between *subjective* and *no rep*?

Comment: @Delan Azabani: Easy enough: subjective -> close votes -> no rep (as few people vote on closed questions).